# Какой командой можно удалить пакет со всеми данными и зависимостями?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package

Команда `apt-get purge пакет`

```
apt-get remove пакет
```

неподходят, так как мне нужно не только один пакет удалить, а ещё и все его зависимости.

Comment: Совсем корректный ответ -- никакой. Данные програм, которые возникли за время использования программы, не удаляются автоматически. Если упустить этот шаг, то вам надо смотреть в сторону удаления осиротевших листьев репозитория. Я честно говоря не помню про Debian, но наверняка что-то такое там есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого в apt есть ключ `--purge`.

> **--purge**
>
> Use purge instead of remove for anything that would be removed. An
>   asterisk ("*") will be displayed next to packages which are scheduled
>   to be purged.  `remove --purge` is equivalent to the **purge**
>   command. Configuration Item: `APT::Get::Purge`.

Наберите так:

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge пакет
```

Answer (score 5):

```
aptitude purge <пакет> && apt-get autoremove && aptitude purge ~c
```

Если прога создаст через `touch /etc/someone-file`, то удалять только руками. Потому что такое в менеджере пакетов не регистрируется.